# useEffect with redux prop updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that I can use multiple times on a page. What it does is make an external call and save a value from that external call to redux store in a key object. I only want the component to do this once so I was using the componentDidMount. Now if the same component gets used again on the page I don't want it to do the external call again. This works correctly using Classes but when I try to use function hooks this no longer works. 
Let me start with showing you the Class based code.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.wait(), 0);
  }

  wait() {
    const { key, map } = this.props;
    if (map[key] === undefined) {
      saveKey(key);
      console.log('LOAD EXTERNAL ID ONLY ONCE');
      externalAPI(this.externalHandler.bind(this));
    }
  }

  externalHandler(value) {
    const { key, setValue } = this.props;
    setValue(key, value);
  }

  render() {
    const { key, map children } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        {children}
      </>
    );
  }
} 

mapStateToProps .....

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { saveKey, setValue })(MyComponent);
```

**Reducer.js**

```
export default (state = {}, action = null) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_KEY: {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.id]: 'default',
      };
    }

    case SET_VALUE: {
      const { id, value } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        [id]: value,
      };
    }

    default: return state;
  }
};
```

**Page.js** 
Calls each component like below.

```
import React from 'react';

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MyComponent key='xxxxx'>First Component</MyComponent>
      <MyComponent key='xxxxx'>Second Component</MyComponent>
    </>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

The above all works. So when the first component mounts i delay a call to redux, not sure why this works but it does. Can someone tell me why using the setTimeout works??? and not using the setTimeout does not. By works I mean with the timeout, first component mounts sets key because map[key] === undefined. Second component mounts map[key] is no longer undefined. But without the timeout map[key] is always === undefined ?

It stores the passed key prop in redux. The Second component mounts and sees the same key is stored so it doesn't need to call the external API getExternalID again. If a third component mounted with a different key then it should run the external API call again and so on.

As I said the above all works except I'm not sure why I needed to do a setTimout to get it to work.

**Second question** turning this into a function and hooks instead of a Class. This does not work for some reason.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ children, key, map, saveKey, setValue }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => delay(), 0);
  }, [map[key]]);

  const delay = () => {
    if (map[key] === undefined) {
      saveKey(key);
      console.log('LOAD VARIANT ONLY ONCE');
      externalAPI(externalHandler);
    }
  };

  const externalHandler = (value) => {
    setValue(key, value);
  };


  return (
      <>
        {children}
      </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question:**

Javascript works with a single thread, so even when you use delay 0 ms, the method is called after React's render method exit. Here is an experiment that I believe explains that for that :

```
function log(msg){
   $("#output").append("<br/>"+msg);
}
function render(){
  log("In render");
  log("Delayed by 0 ms without setTimeout...")
  setTimeout(() =>log("Delayed by 0 ms with setTimeout..."), 0);
  for(var i = 0;i<10;i++) log("Delay inside render "+i);
  log("Render finish");
}
render();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hqbj5xdr/

So actually all the components render once before they start checking if map[key] is undefined.

**Second question:**

In your example, it is not really clear where map and saveKey come from. And how map is shared between components...

Anyway, a naive solution is to directly update the map. And make sure that all component
refers to this map instance (not a copy).

```
if (map[key] === undefined) {
      map[key]=true;
      saveKey(key);
      console.log('LOAD VARIANT ONLY ONCE');
      externalAPI(externalHandler);
    }
```

But that is a little bad (sharing reference). So a better design may be to use a cache. Don't pass the map, but a getter and a setter. getKey and saveKey. Underlying those methods may use a map to persist which key has been set.

Comment: Thanks semako. I thought componentDidMount is reacts way of saying the same 'React's render method exit' React did its first render and you are safe to do anything with the dom or anything else for that matter. In my case your component is rendered go call an external api.

Comment: Second question. saveKey is an action and you can see that from my code. export default connect(mapStateToProps, { saveKey, setValue })(MyComponent);                           map is a prop from redux store which is gotten from mapStateToProps. Its the object key I talked about in my opening comments. Its an object in Redux that stores the key. Which you can see in my Reducer code.

Comment: Yes, componentDidMount is a good place to go call an external API. However if you are doing it in set timeout, it happens out of sync with react lifecycle.

Comment: In this case, the best idea may be to remove the API call from the component and put it inside a reducer... https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions